# Como usar os serviços do IBM Cloud com requisição POST em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, request, ibm

Estou tentando utilizar o serviço "Speech To Text" da IBM Cloud na minha aplicação Python através de requisições POST com o pacote `requests`.

O problema é que estou confuso sobre a URL que deve ser utilizada e também a forma da requisição. Eu vi alguns tutoriais na internet nos quais o rapaz utiliza a seguinte URL:

```
https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize
```

Porém ao ir na parte de **Gerenciamento** do serviço, a URL que obtenho é esta:

```
https://api.us-east.speech-to-text.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/<um código aqui>
```

O meu código Python é este:

```
import requests

api_url = "<Uma das URL's que coloquei acima na pergunta>"
key = "<Chave da API (a chave está correta)>"

with open("audio.wav", "rb") as file:
    audio = file.read()

response = requests.post(
    api_url,
    data = audio,
    headers = {"Content-Type": "audio/wav"},
    auth = ("apikey", key)
)

print(response.content)
```

Quando tento utilizar a primeira URL eu obtenho esta resposta:

> b'{"code":403, "error": "Forbidden"}'

E ao utilizar a segunda URL eu obtenho isto:

> b'{"code":404, "error": "Not Found"}'.

O que eu estou fazendo de errado na requisição?

Comment: Antes que me perguntem se eu já tentei utilizar o pacote `ibm_watson`, sim eu já tentei, porém achei ele muito complicado. Logo, preferi utilizar o pacote `requests` que penso ser mais simples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/speech-to-text?topic=speech-to-text-gettingStarted), você deve utilizar o *endpoint* `/v1/recognize` a partir da URL base que você recebe. Essa URL base que você recebe é a:

```
https://<region>.speech-to-text.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/<uuid>
```

<sup>Deixo [aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fby2O.png) uma imagem indicando onde obter essa URL base.</sup>

Então, a sua requisição POST será para:

```
https://<region>.speech-to-text.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/<uuid>/v1/recognize
```

Creio que o seu erro era não estar utilizando a URL correta. Lembre-se também de verificar se as chaves de API estão corretas. :)

---

Com isso, o seu código Python ficará assim:

```py
import requests

base_api_url = "https://api.us-south.speech-to-text.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/<uuid>"
key = "<secret>"

with open("audio.wav", "rb") as file:
    audio = file.read()

response = requests.post(
    f"{base_api_url}/v1/recognize",
    data = audio,
    headers = { "Content-Type": "audio/wav" },
    auth = ("apikey", key)
)

print(response.content.decode("utf-8"))
```

Para solicitar por um modelo de idioma diferente do inglês, você deve acrescentar o parâmetro `language_customization_id` à URL, conforme [consta na documentação](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/speech-to-text?topic=speech-to-text-languageUse).

Para fazer isso usando a biblioteca `requests`, basta usar a opção `params`, conforme também [consta na documentação](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls).

Assim:

```py
import requests

base_api_url = "https://api.us-south.speech-to-text.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/<uuid>"
key = "<secret>"

with open("audio.wav", "rb") as file:
    audio = file.read()

response = requests.post(
    f"{base_api_url}/v1/recognize",
    # Aqui você passa os atributos da URL:
    params= { "language_customization_id": "<lang-code>" },
    data = audio,
    headers = { "Content-Type": "audio/wav" },
    auth = ("apikey", key)
)

print(response.content.decode("utf-8"))
```

No entanto, não pude testar, já que aparentemente é um recurso que exige um plano diferente do meu (o gratuito de testes). Estava recebendo um erro 400. :)

Comment: Cara muito obrigado, eu estava quebrando muito a cabeça por isso kk. No caso seria o mesmo para os outros serviços da IBM ou só para este ?

Comment: Como não sou um conhecedor das APIs do Watson, não tenho como te responder com certeza. Contudo, imagino que exista um padrão sim, já que se trata de um mesmo serviço com diferentes “sub serviços”, como esse do Speech to Text. :)

Comment: Luiz, me desculpe mas vou precisar te incomodar só mais um pouquinho porque não tenho muito conhecimento sobre requisições kkk. Eu sei que existe uma forma de definir o idioma utilizando o parâmetro `model`, porém como eu faria isso na requisição ? Por exemplo, agora ele me dá o texto em inglês e eu quero em português.

Comment: @JeanExtreme002, editei a resposta. Penso que baste enviar um parâmetro pela URL. Conforme coloquei na edição, a biblioteca que você está utilizando cobre [este caso de uso](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) na documentação. :)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda Luiz <3